# How Series FET connected opposite to each other operates?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, driver, fet

Two FETs are connected in series opposite to each other. See the following circuit diagram. I am confused here that when both FETs are turned on, How does it allow current to flow? but in the simulation, it is not working. I am confused about the schematic diagram available on [bq77905](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua773/slua773.pdf?ts=1695850279112). The schematic is shown on page no 3. Where multiple charge and discharge FETs are connected in parallel opposite to each other. How it is working?

[image: FET Series Connection]

Comment: Q1 fails suddenly from exceeding Vgs(max). Are you *sure* this is an accurate representation of the linked diagram?

Comment: No, I have created this diagram on Proteus. I think my diagram may be wrong. But I am confused about the schematic diagram for battery management available on https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua773/slua773.pdf?ts=1695850279112 . Where they used FETs. Please guide me on how these FETs allow current to the battery or to load. When both FETs are turned from IC.

Comment: think about the MOSFET body diode

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done to prevent current flowing in both directions.  The app note uses Q1, 3, 5, and 7 to prevent current from flowing from the battery backwards into the charging supply; unlike your purely resistive load, the battery is also capable of sourcing current.

As shown here, the left switch is irrelevant, since the body diode will conduct all the time anyway; the right switch will allow the load voltage to rise to 5V-Vgs.  Assuming, that is, that Q1 survives the large voltage differential between the gate at 5V and the source at 60V.

If you intend to use it as in the app note, connect the negative of the 5V source to the 60V supply to provide +5V gate-source drive to the FETs.

Note also the G-S resistors in the app note (R16 and R17), they're important.  Without them, the gates can float, leading to undefined results.